# Testing for non-repeating integers in a RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need my Regular Expression to not have any repeating decimals unless I specify so.

For example, I have a RegExp `/[12]{2}/`

This is just saying that I need to have 2 digits, either 1 or 2. I want to reject the string if it was 11 or 22, but have it pass if the numbers weren't repeating. So it could either be 12 or 21. So the way I check to make sure 11 or 22 aren't passed is by checking after the first RegExp with this: `!(/^.*(.).*\1.*$/`

Therefore, if n is 12 or 21, then it'll pass, but not with 11 or 22.

Now here comes my problem. I'd like to not have repeating numbers unless it's necessary. Say for example my RegExp is `/[494]{3}/`. I'd like to have it where there would be no more than two 4s in my number. So the only acceptable numbers would be 494, 449, 944, but not 444, 499, 994, 999 etc...

If I try and use my previous two tests to check for multiples of any digit, then it will reject any number that I input because a digit repeats.

How can I create a regular expression where it allows for a digit to be used in any order and not repeated, unless otherwise stated?

Comment: Is requirement to use `RegExp`? Is input always either two, or three characters?

Comment: js just count by letter

Comment: _"I'd like to have it where there would be no more than two 4s in my number. So the only acceptable numbers would be 494, 449, 944, but not 444, 499, 994, 999 etc..."_ `499`, `994` have less than three `4`s. Do you mean that any individual number should not occur more than twice? Where `499`, `994` should pass condition of containing no more than two of any number?

Comment: RegExp isn't a requirement, this was just the way I attempted. There are a lot of inputs, and I have a lot of expressions to check, so I thought this method would be the best.

Comment: Any individual number shouldn't occuer more than once. So for every 4, there should only be one for in the expression. If there are two 4s in the expression, then the expression must have two 4s.